# If Else and Javascript what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I think there is an issue in my if else statement as I think it is giving me the opposite result of what I'm expecting.

```
console.log(_.map(item, function(n){return _.find(n).tertiary})) 
//is undefined.

console.log(_.map(item, function(n){return _.find(n).primary}));
//is ["green"]

I use the following if statement to assign a value to my variable:

if(_.map(item, function(n){return _.find(n).tertiary}) === undefined ){
   var audience = _.map(item, function(n){return _.find(n).tertiary});
   } else {
   var audience = _.map(item, function (n) {return _.find(n).primary});
   }

console.log(audience);//this is undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this working correctly? I expect the answer to be ["green"].

Comment: yeah I think its fine, as your first condition seems to be true and its not falling to the `else` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your if else to:

```
if(_.map(item, function(n){return _.find(n).tertiary}) === undefined ){//since tertiary is undefined, so use primary instead
    var audience = _.map(item, function (n) {return _.find(n).primary});
} else {
    var audience = _.map(item, function(n){return _.find(n).tertiary});
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Duh?!? I've been looking at this too long.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a little variety:

```
var colours = _.map(item, function(n){
    return {primary: _.find(n).primary, tertiary: _.find(n).tertiary}
})

var audience = colours.primary || colours.tertiary

console.log(audience)
```

Although underscore/lodash could probably lend a hand in getting those values out in a cleaner manner.